# Replacing some characters in a text column in R

Tags: r, text, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with a text column that includes texts and a term that starts with a term such as `sa`  and with two `following digits`  after. The letters can be anything from a to z and either small or capital. A snapshot of the data is as follows:

```
df_new <- data.frame(
  given_info=c('SA12 is given','he has his sa12',
         'she will get Sr15','why not having an ra31',
         'his tA23 is missing', 'pa12 is given'))

df_new %>% select(given_info)

              given_info
1          SA12 is given
2        he has his sa12
3      she will get Sr15
4 why not having an ra31
5    his tA23 is missing
6          pa12 is given
```

I need to replace any term that has the `sa (or any other combinations of two random letters with the two digits`  after with the term `document` . Hence, the outcome of interest is:

```
              given_info
1          document is given
2        he has his document
3      she will get document
4      why not having an document
5    his document is missing
6          document is given
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub()` here as follows:

```r
df_new$given_info <- gsub("\\b[A-Za-z]{2}\\d{2}\\b", "document", df_new$given_info)
df_new

                  given_info
1          document is given
2        he has his document
3      she will get document
4 why not having an document
5    his document is missing
6          document is given
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `\b` a word boundary (meaning what precedes is NOT a word character)
- `[A-Za-z]{2}` match any 2 letters
- `\d{2}` match 2 digits
- `\b` another word boundary (what follows the digits is NOT a word character)

The word boundaries ensure, for example, that `abc12` in your text does not get replaced with `document`.  If we didn't use the word boundaries, then you would also get substring matches, which maybe you don't want.

Comment: My apologies, just noticed that there are different variations of the terms in my dataset. I hope you can resolve it.

Comment: @Alex I have updated my answer per your comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  the first ```2``` refers to the number of letters? I mean if a term starts with ```3``` letters, I should change it to ```3```?  and the second ```2``` refers to the number of digits I assume?

Comment: Check the updated answer for an explanation.

Comment: thanks a lot. it helped so much. Are you actively answering questions here?

Comment: @Alex Yes, check my profile to see my activity.

Comment: thanks! Just visited and hope you enjoy the coffee I sent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251437/discussion-between-alex-and-tim-biegeleisen).